# Serving a Scraper Tool as an API Using FastAPI for Multiple Users and Associating Runs with User IDs

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, celery, fastapi

I've developed a scraper tool that performs searches on a website based on an input query, retrieves necessary data, and returns it in JSON format. This tool utilizes Selenium along with Chromedriver and typically takes around a minute or two to execute.

My goal is to serve this scraper tool as an API using FastAPI. Each user of the tool should have a 'run' associated with their user ID, reflecting the instance when the tool was utilized, alongside the respective data fetched during that run.

I'm seeking advice on the best practices and strategies for implementing this API to handle multiple users effectively. Specifically, how can I ensure concurrent use of the tool by different users without interference? Additionally, what are the recommended approaches for associating each run with the respective user ID and the data retrieved during that run?

Any insights, examples, or suggestions on architecting this setup using FastAPI and handling multiple users' access to the scraper tool through an API would be immensely helpful.

Researched on celery and BackgroundTasks